# pick an image save and show, ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT error

Tags: android

sorry for my English
in my app I want to add an imageView, when pressed the user can pick an image and assign it to a book, save it and show it
so in my add book activity I added a registerForActivityResult (since i saw start for activity result is deprecated), and added an on click listener, here is the code

```
private var imageUri: Uri? = null
private val imagePicker =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
        uri?.let {
            imageUri = it
            binding.imageView.setImageURI(imageUri)
        }
    }
```

image view on click

```
binding.imageView.setOnClickListener {
        imagePicker.launch("image/*")
    }
```

add book function

```
private fun addBook() {
    // fetching info
    val name: String = binding.nameEditText.text.toString()
    val author: String = binding.authorEditText.text.toString()
    val desc: String = binding.descEditText.text.toString()
    //val imgurl: String = binding.imgurlEditText.text.toString()

    // create book
    val book = Book(name, author, desc, imageUri)

    // adding book
    bookViewModel.addToAllBooks(book)

    // showing message
    Toast.makeText(this, "Book has been added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

(this function is set to the on click of an add button)

im using Room db to hold all the books, and one property of the book is the uri (which I added type converter to string using Uri.parse(stringUri)) which I later show in a recycler view and in activity that show one book, I'm using Glide to load the uri (not sure if necessary)

when I leaving the add book activity to the main activity that has fragment that show all book in a recycler view, the image is loaded correctly, but when I click on a book to open book activity I get this error (which does not crash my app but my image view shows nothing)

> opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{4ffae1 26378:com.example.mynewlibrary/u0a136} (pid=26378, uid=10136) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

here is the code for loading the image

```
private fun initView(book: Book) {
    // changing app title to book name capitelized
    title = book.name.lowercase()
        .replaceFirstChar { if (it.isLowerCase()) it.titlecase(Locale.getDefault()) else it.toString() }

    binding.nameTextView.text = book.name
    binding.authorTextView.text = book.author
    binding.descTextView.text = book.desc

    Glide.with(this).load(book.imageUri).into(binding.imageView)
}
```

(same method is used in the recycler view which works)

I have another question which might affect this one, I don't want if the user delete the image from the galley the image will be removed from my app, I'm not sure how it works (and I would have tried it if not the above error), if that how it works I would like to save the image in the app storage so even when deleted the app still has it image. if you know how to do it I will be happy to hear (or even only the method name and will do my research)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > which I later show in a recycler view and in activity that show one book

If you use the uri later or in another activity then your right to read the content behind that uri is gone. The right does not persist.

So instead of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Then in onActivityResult() take persistable uri permission in order to .. persist your read/write access to that uri.

> > ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()

That equals `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

Comment: it worked, just to make i did the right thing about the second half (the persistable uri permission) i added contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(it,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) inside the registerForActivityResult  
and now i checked about what i wrote at the end (the delete picture and save it) seems it does being saved even im deleting, so it works great  
thanks alot